# Force the phone to beep when a specific e-mail arrives, even on silent mode?

Tags: email, silent-mode, alerts

My phone is usually in silent mode and I keep it that way because in my country, phone service providers spam A LOT with both SMS and phone calls. But sometimes I receive important e-mails, I'd like to have something that makes it beep, even on silent mode, when a specific e-mail comes.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

[Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en_US&gl=US) can achieve this fairly easily, with basic instructions coming from [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/tasker/comments/msfjvn/can_i_use_tasker_to_alert_me_of_email_from/).

1. Create a new task in tasker using Event -> Notification
2. Set your email application as the "Owner Application"
3. Set additional email options (such as notification title for sender name)
4. Go back, and select "New Task"
5. Give it a title, then select Audio -> Notification volume and set it to a level above zero

This will leave your notification sounds on until you disable them again, but alternatively, for step 5 you could use One of the options under the Alert actions to create a one-time alert.